# Model Association and getting values from DB in to views - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Below is the schema of my "Communications" table,

```
id | UserID | CommunicationMode | CommunicationDetail
```

UserID is the foreign key in "Communications" table And below is the schema of users table:

```
id | First_name | email
```

And I want to get the values "CommunicationMode" and "CommunicationDetail" columns and put it into the text_field:

**Controller:**

```
def new
   @user_communication=User.where(UserID: current_user.id)
end
```

And below is the model of communication:

```
class Communication < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :UserID, presence: true
end
```

And below is the model of user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :educations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :professions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :communications, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :availabilities,dependent: :destroy
    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    before_create :create_remember_token
    validates :First_Name, presence: true,length: {maximum: 50}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness:  { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
    has_secure_password


    def User.new_remember_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def User.encrypt(token)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
    end

    private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
    end
end
```

ANd below is the code of new.html.erb page:

```
 <table>
          <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Email:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <%= text_field :email,:placeholder => "Email" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Phone:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <%= text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Phone" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Skype:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <%= text_field :skype,:placeholder => "Skype" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Website:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <%= text_field :website,:placeholder => "Website" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                Twitter:
             </td>
             <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
                <%= text_field :twitter, :placeholder => "Twitter" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

How сould I get the values from DB and put it into the text_field?

Comment: Can you just post the models Communication and User?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid user in `@user_communication`, you can get his communications as given below.

**Controller:**

```
unless @user_communication == nil
  @user_communications = @user_communication.communications
end
```

Then from the model specifications, it is clear that one user can have multiple communications.

So, in view just loop through `@user_communications` and get the field values `CommunicationMode` and `CommunicationDetail` from each of his communication.

**View:**

```
<% unless @user_communications.blank? %>
  <% @user_communications.each do |user_com| %>

     <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Communication Mode:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            <%= text_field :cmode, :placeholder => "Communication Mode", :value => user_com.CommunicationMode %>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;">
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            Communication Mode:
         </td>
         <td style="font-size: large; color: #212121;">
            <%= text_field :cdetail, :placeholder => "Communication Detail", :value => user_com.CommunicationDetail %>
         </td>
      </tr>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Did you try anything?